# Message Handler function with Filter.command & Filter.photo not working

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am working on a image editing telegram bot - which can perform various functions based on commands like crop , removebg, etc.The idea is to accept single or multiple images from the user and get a command i.e. **/crop** or **/removebg** and get the bot to return edited images.

- I am using the python-telegram-bot library and I am unable to trigger
  the message handler dispatcher defined as follows:

`dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.command('crop') & (Filters.photo),crop))`

whereas, something like Filters.caption works perfectly fine as below

`dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.caption('crop') & (Filters.photo),crop))`

However, it is practically impossible to add captions to each and every image when uploading multiple images.

Entire code pasted below:

```
import requests
import telegram
from io import BytesIO
import imgpro
import os
import cv2
import logging
from telegram import Update
from removebg import RemoveBg
import cv2
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
import os
import io, requests, cv2, numpy as np
from telegram.ext.callbackcontext import CallbackContext
from telegram.ext.messagehandler import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import (
Updater,
MessageHandler,
CommandHandler,
CallbackQueryHandler,
CallbackContext,
ConversationHandler,
PicklePersistence,
filters)
from telegram.ext.filters import Filters
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ForceReply

botToken='bototken'
global fileSavePath
fileSavePath=".\\trial.jpeg"

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

##########################FUNCTION BLOCK####################################################

def cropImage(filePath,fileSavePath):
    ## Crop Borders from Images based on hard coded percentage reduction ##
    ## Useful for removing borders from Night Wear Images with Design Numbers,etc.
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(filePath.read(), np.uint8), 1)
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    redH=np.round(height*0.05,0)
    redW=np.round(width*0.11,0)
    y=0+int(redH)
    x=0+int(redW)
    h=height-int(redH)
    w=width-int(redW)
    crop_image = image[x:w, y:h]
    crop_image = image[y:h, x:w]
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite(fileSavePath, crop_image)
    return('crop_image')

############################TELEGRAM BLOCK###################################################
def cropb(update, context):
    #Function to crop borders from photos
    length = len(update.message.photo)
    print ('Photos in this message:', length)
 
    for n in range(0, length):
        file = context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[n].file_id)
        f =  BytesIO(file.download_as_bytearray())
        cropImage(f,fileSavePath)
        update.message.reply_photo(photo=open(".\\trial.jpeg", 'rb'))

def crop(update, context):
    #Funtion to crop borders from 1 photo
    file = context.bot.get_file(update.message.photo[-1].file_id)
    file.download('.\\trial2.jpeg')
    f =  BytesIO(file.download_as_bytearray())
    cropImage(f,fileSavePath)
    update.message.reply_photo(photo=open(".\\trial.jpeg", 'rb'))


def main():
    telegram_bot_token = botToken
    updater = Updater(token=telegram_bot_token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.command('crop') & (Filters.photo),crop))
    # dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, crop))
    # dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, crop))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Github Question [link](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/3328)

Comment: This question was also asked at https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/3328

Comment: thanks for pointing out. added links in both questions